# Why i can not to connect oracle database with c# windows application?

Tags: c#, oracle

I'm beginner in oracle database ,want to write simple application to connect to the oracle database,write this code:

```
OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection();
            conn.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS_LIST =(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521)))(CONNECT_DATA =(SERVICE_NAME = behbehzad)))";
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                conn.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("Connect Successfull!!");
            }
            catch (Exception e1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e1.ToString());

            }
```

but when run the application get this error:
[image]

How can i solve that?thanks.

Comment: I presume that you gave the wrong parameters in your connectionstring. You can get help from http://www.connectionstrings.com/ how to write the correct connectionstring you need

Answer (score 1):

The error ORA-12514 means that a listener received a request to establish a connection to a database or other service. The connect descriptor received by the listener specified a service name for a service (usually a database service) that either has not yet dynamically registered with the listener or has not been statically configured for the listener. This may be a temporary condition such as after the listener has started, but before the database instance has registered with the listener.

The possible resolutions for this error are

- Check which services are currently known by the listener by executing:

`lsnrctl services <listener name>`

- Check that the SERVICE_NAME parameter in the connect descriptor of the net service name used specifies a service known by the listener.
- If an easy connect naming connect identifier was used, check that the service name specified is a service known by the listener
- Check for an event in the listener.log file
- Check your Oracle PATH configuration on Windows
- Change your connection string

And you can read this [solution](http://dba-oracle.com/t_ora_12514_tns_listener_does_not_currently_know_service_requested.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
conn.ConnectionString = @"localhost:1521/behbehzad";
```

No need to make it more complicated than it is.